# PATH order different in vim terminal window

Tags: terminal

I have anaconda set up with a few different environments.  When I switch environments and open vim 8.2 and type `:term` to launch a terminal window and type `echo $PATH`, $PATH does not match what is shown in a terminal outside of vim.  If instead just type `:!echo $PATH`, it is correct

getting path from the terminal outside of vim:

```
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@ip-172-31-50-75:~$ echo $PATH
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/bin:/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin:/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/condabin:/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/usr/local/mpi/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ubuntu/.dl_binaries/bin:/usr/local/mpi/bin:/opt/aws/neuron/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/usr/local/mpi/bin:/opt/amazon/openmpi/bin:/opt/amazon/efa/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

getting path using `:! echo $PATH` from vim command mode (matches $PATH above):

```
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/bin:/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin:/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/condabin:/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/usr/local/mpi/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ubuntu/.dl_binaries/bin:/usr/local/mpi/bin:/opt/aws/neuron/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/usr/local/mpi/bin:/opt/amazon/openmpi/bin:/opt/amazon/efa/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Opening a terminal window within vim and checking $PATH (first 11 directories are duplicates that appear later in $PATH):

```
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@ip-172-31-50-75:~$ echo $PATH                                                                                                                                          
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/usr/local/mpi/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ubuntu/.dl_binaries/bin:/usr/local/mpi/bin:/opt/aws/neuron/bin:/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/bin:/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin:/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/condabin:/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/usr/local/mpi/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ubuntu/.dl_binaries/bin:/usr/local/mpi/bin:/opt/aws/neuron/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/usr/local/mpi/bin:/opt/amazon/openmpi/bin:/opt/amazon/efa/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Trying to understand why $PATH within a vim terminal window has additional directories prepended...

Comment: Open a normal terminal with your anaconda setup. Then just execute `bash` (or whatever shell you use). How does the PATH look like.

Comment: interesting... looks the same as the last one I listed, from opening a terminal window in vim and checking PATH

Comment: There are some relatively tricky rules around what files are used to initialize bash and when. To get a taste `man bash` and find the section named `INVOCATION`. It's also possible to configure vim to do something different on top of that (e.g. with the various `'shell*`' settings). I don't know much about Anaconda but that might be adding additional variables to the mix. So your question as posed has more than one possible answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the "anaconda setup", but assume it is included in your shells configuration files (like `.bashrc`). It seems to manipulate the `PATH` environment variable.

When you open a terminal from within Vim a second instance of the shell is started, causing a manipulation of the `PATH` that was already manipulated. Hence the different value of `PATH`.

If this behavior is a problem, you can change your shell configuration to not repeat the anaconda stuff if it was already done.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks.  I'll look in to fixing that.